# Hide the checkbox from a QListView item

Tags: c++, qt

I wave a `QListView` that is backed by a `QStandardItemModel`. Under certain circonstances, the `QStandardItem` are made checkable. A checkbox gets displayed besides the item's display. At some point, I want to remove hide the `QStandardItem` checkbox. I set its checkable state to false but it doesn't hide the checkbox (though it cannot be checked anymore).

The only way I have found of hiding the checkbox is to replace the item with a new one. This doesn't seem the proper way to preceed.

This is the code:

```
MyModel::MyModel(QObject *parent):QStandardItemModel(parent){}

void MyModel::createItem(int row, const QString &text)
{
   setItem(row, new QStandardItem(text));
}

void MyModel::setCheckable(int row)
{
   item(row)->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
   item(row)->setCheckable(true); // A checkbox appears besides the text
}

void MyModel::hideCheckBox(int row)
{
   item(row)->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
   item(row)->setCheckable(false); // does not work

   // I need to completely replace the item for the checkbox to disapear.
   // This doesn't seem the proper way to proceed
   setItem(row, new QStandardItem(item(row)->data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString()));
}
```

Is there better way to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `setCheckState` or `setCheckable`, the qt will update the data of list item by adding or setting a `Qt::CheckStateRole` data. If the `Qt::CheckStateRole` data is existed, the check icon will be shown. So you need remove it from the data map of the list item.

Finally, the code of `hideCheckBox` should be:

```
void MyModel::hideCheckBox(int row)
{
    // check the item pointer
    QStandardItem* pitem = item(row);
    if (pitem == NULL) return;

    // find and delete the Qt::CheckStateRole data
    QMap<int, QVariant> mdata = itemData(pitem->index());
    if (mdata.remove(Qt::CheckStateRole))
    {
        setItemData(pitem->index(), mdata);
    }
}
```

Hope it useful. :)

Comment: One would expect that setCheckable(false) does that internally.

Comment: Yes, it will call 'setData(Qt::Unchecked, Qt::CheckStateRole);' if the item is not checkable when call `setCheckable`. It will try to add a `Qt::CheckStateRole` to data map when call `setData`. You can see the [source code](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/c8172953ed6d3776178b9a37c0773d648cfdd9f2:src/gui/itemmodels/qstandarditemmodel.cpp).

Comment: @Alex Thanks for the answer! Instead of going through the 'itemData()' map to clear the `Qt::CheckStateRole`, writing QVariant() does the same. Therefore, my final code would be this one liner: `item(row)->setData(QVariant(), Qt::CheckStateRole);`

Answer (score -1):

I think the presence of the check boxes in items defined by item flags, so that I would write the function in the following way:

```
void MyModel::hideCheckBox(int row)
{
   // Does not set the Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable flag.
   item(row)->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsSelectable | Qt::ItemIsEnabled);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried to use your method, but it didn't work.